# jquery loadmore not working as desired

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have used jquery AJAX to load more posts from MySQL database. It brings up the right content and works just fine.

The only problem is that it displays the data after the first two pictures every time. 
Let's say there are 10 pictures in total and the first 2 are already displayed.

image 1
image 2

When the load more button is clicked here is how it looks
image 1
image 2
image 3
image 4

Now if i press the load more button again, here is how it displays the content

image 1
image 2
image 5
image 6
image 3
image 4

If i press it again it will paste the 7 and 8 after the 1 and 2 and so on

Here is my HTML

```
            $rowperpage = 2;
            $select_count=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT count(*) as allcount from gif where status = 1");
            $select_data=mysqli_fetch_array($select_count);
            $allcount=$select_data['allcount'];
            $run=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM gif WHERE status=1 order by id desc limit ".$rowperpage);
            if(!$run){
            echo mysqli_error($con);
            }
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run)) {
                $image=$row['gif'];
                $id=$row['id'];
                $title=$row['title'];
                ?>
                <div class = "load-more-post">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <div classs="panel panel-info">
                        <div classs="panel panel-body ">

                            <a href='blog.php?gifId=<?php echo $id; ?>'><img src="Uploads/<?php echo $image; ?> " class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail"  style='height: 260px; width: 250px; '></a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>

            <?php }?>
 <h1 class="load-more">Load More</h1>
 <input type="hidden" id="row" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
 <input type="hidden" id="all" value="<?php echo $allcount; ?>">
```

Here is my Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// Load more data
$('.load-more').click(function(){
    var row = Number($('#row').val());
    var allcount = Number($('#all').val());
    //row = row + 2;

    if(row != 4){
        $("#row").val(row);


      $.ajax({
            url: 'getData.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {row:row},
            beforeSend:function(){
                $(".load-more").text("Loading...");
            },
            success: function(response){

                // Setting little delay while displaying new content
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // appending posts after last post with class="post"
                    $(".load-more-post").after(response);
                    //var rowno = row + 2;
                    var thenewid = Number($('#newid').val());
                  alert(thenewid);
                    $("#row").val(thenewid);
                    // checking row value is greater than allcount or not
                    if(thenewid == 4){


                        // Change the text and background
                        $('.load-more').text("No more posts");
                        $('.load-more').addClass('inactiveLink');

                    }
                    else{
                        $(".load-more").text("Load more");
                    }
                }, 2000);


            }
        });
    }


});

});
```

and here is the PHP file where I am getting my datafrom. getData.php

```
 $row = $_POST['row'];
$rowperpage = 2;

// selecting posts
$run=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM gif WHERE status=1 and id < $row order by id desc limit ".$rowperpage);
            if(!$run){
            echo mysqli_error($con);
            }



while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
$image=$row['gif'];
                $id=$row['id'];
                $title=$row['title'];
                ?>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
                    <div classs="panel panel-info">
                        <div classs="panel panel-body" >

                            <a href='blog.php?gifId=<?php echo $id; ?>'><img src="Uploads/<?php echo $image; ?> " class="img img-responsive img-thumbnail"  style='height: 260px; width: 250px; '></a>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            <?php       
      }?>

      <input type="hidden" id="newid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
```

Comment: Which is the line that actually inserts the new content to the DOM?  This?:  `$(".load-more-post:first").after(response);`  There are no matching elements in your code, so how would that insert anything at all?

Comment: YEs, I forgot adding that one tag. I have corrected it now.

Comment: But the error is there. Can you find out the error now? 
Thanks

Comment: Do some debugging to narrow it down a bit.  What is the state of the HTML before the line of code which adds the new elements?  What is the exact line of code?  What is the state of the HTML after that line of code executes?  It seems that's the specific point at which the problem manifests, right?  Remove the unrelated parts and focus on specifically that operation.

Comment: I have tried a few things, Javascript simply outplays my skill set. Any help would be appreciated at the moment.

Comment: Well, at this point we're just talking about using your browser's debugging tools. Set breakpoints in the AJAX callback that adds the content to the page. Examine the state of the HTML in the browser's DOM explorer (when you click "inspect element" when right clicking on the page for example) before and after each line of code.  Find where this is happening and specifically what is happening.  Chances are you just need to identify a different place to append the new content.

Answer (score 0):

You use

```
$(".load-more-post").after(response);
```

to insert your new posts after the `.load-more-post` div. This particular div is wrapped around your initial posts, so that explains why it gets added there. If you want the oldest always be the last, I'd suggest to use `.before` instead, like so:

```
$(".load-more").before(response);
```

Comment: This makes it worse. First of all, the logic fails and I receive the same files every time once the first files are fetched.

Comment: and secondly, the styles are lost

Comment: That's because you are using the `id` attribute multiple times (with every fetch, you add `<input type="hidden" id="newid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">` to your document. Notice how you set the id? So in the end you will several elements with the `id="newid"`. This is invalid HTML. IDs have to be unique in the whole DOM. Because JS assumes there will only be one element `#newid` it will simply take the first one it finds and therefore the value of newid never changes.

Either remove old `#newid` elements before you do the fetch or you use a class instead and select the last one with `.last()`